# How to cascade (soft) delete has many relationships in GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am implementing some delete functionality using GORM. My idea is to cascade delete where when the parent row is deleted the childern are deleted aswell. I have tried the [delete with select](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select). But it only deletes the parent record.

```golang
func DeleteProject(db *gorm.DB, id uint) (Project, error) {
    var project Project
    if err := db.Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&project, id).Error; err != nil {
        return Project{}, err
    }
    return project, nil
}
```

I have the following model:

```golang
type Project struct {
    ID           uint           `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt    gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    TicketNumber string         `gorm:"size:6;unique;not null" json:"ticketnumber"`
    Name         string         `json:"name"`
    MailingList  string         `json:"mailinglist"`
    Environment  string         `gorm:"not null" json:"environment"`
    UserID       uint           `gorm:"index" json:"user_id"`
    Diagrams     []Diagram      `json:"diagrams"`
}

type Diagram struct {
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Data      string         `json:"data"`
    ProjectID uint           `gorm:"index" json:"project_id"`
    Instances []Instance     `json:"instances"`
}

type Instance struct {
    ID        uint           `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    CreatedAt time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"deleted_at"`
    Key       uint           `json:"key"`
    DiagramID uint           `gorm:"index" json:"diagram_id"`
}
```

Where a project can have multiple diagrams and a diagram can have multiple instances. But when I am running the `DeleteProject` function it is only deleting the `Project` and not the associated diagrams and instances.

How can I delete a project and it's associated diagrams and instances in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an solution, but I think it is not optimal for cascade delete, it solved my problem at least. I've coded the following:

First the `DeleteProject` function, where I loop over all `Diagrams` and call the `DeleteDiagram` function and finally I also clear all associations with this project before deleting the project.

```golang
//Delete a project and it's associations.
func DeleteProject(db *gorm.DB, id uint) (Project, error) {
    project, err := GetProject(db, id)
    if err != nil {
        return Project{}, err
    }
    if len(project.Diagrams) > 0 {
        for _, projectDiagram := range project.Diagrams {
            _, err := DeleteDiagram(db, projectDiagram.ID)
            if err != nil {
                return Project{}, err
            }
        }
        db.Model(&project).Association("Diagrams").Clear()
    }
    if err := db.Delete(&project, id).Error; err != nil {
        return Project{}, err
    }
    return project, nil
}
```

The `DeleteDiagram` does the same, but then with the `Instances`

```golang
//Delete a diagram and it's associations.
func DeleteDiagram(db *gorm.DB, id uint) (Diagram, error) {
    var diagram, err = GetDiagram(db, id)
    if err != nil {
        return Diagram{}, err
    }
    if len(diagram.Instances) > 0 {
        db.Model(&diagram).Association("Instances").Clear()
        for _, diagramInstance := range diagram.Instances {
            _, err := DeleteInstance(db, diagramInstance.ID)
            if err != nil {
                return Diagram{}, err
            }
        }
    }
    if err := db.Delete(&diagram).Error; err != nil {
        return Diagram{}, err
    }
    return diagram, nil
}
```

Hope it helps.